# pop_front of list not removing element for a list

Tags: c++, stl

I have map with following definition,

```
typedef std::list<HolderClass*> QueueHolderList;
map<string, QueueHolderList > OrderQueue;
```

and am filling above with following push_back way,

```
map<string, QueueHolderList >::iterator itr = OrderQueue.find(val);
if(itr == OrderQueue.end())
{
    QueueHolderList qHolder;
    qHolder.push_back(new HolderClass());
}
else
{
    itr->second.push(new TransactionHolder());
}
```

But when i try to do the remove the element using pop_front (below snippet of code), then its not removing the element, below code is running in while loop and checking OrderQueue and for every val if size is grater then zero then remove the element.

```
map<string, QueueHolderList>::iterator itr;

for(itr = OrderQueue.begin(); itr != OrderQueue.end(); itr++)
{
    string gen2Aotag = itr->first;
    HolderClass q = itr->second;

    if(q.size() > 0)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < q.size(); i++)
        {
            if(q.front())
            {   
                .......... other code ............
                delete q.front();
                q.front() = NULL;
                q.pop_front();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is when i re-iterate the orderQue map, then for same removed item for list is found (though removed using pop_front) and causes seg fault as it point to some garbage location and tries to access the code using that garbage.

Where i went wrong ? or my apporach is not correct ? Please help me identify this.

Comment: `HolderClass q = itr->second;` - this creates a copy.

Comment: `qHolder.push_back(new HolderClass());` were you planning on doing something that that `qHolder` object or did you intend to just let it self-destruct and leak the dynamic allocation you just made?

Answer (score 1):

You are not adding anything to `map`.

```
map<string, QueueHolderList >::iterator itr = OrderQueue.find(val);
if(itr == OrderQueue.end())
{
    QueueHolderList qHolder;
    qHolder.push_back(new HolderClass());
    // This adds an item to the object on the stack but not to the map.

    // You need:
    OrderQueue[val] = qHolder;
}
else
{
    itr->second.push(new TransactionHolder());
}
```